# Compiling x264 on a Mac: "No working C compiler found" and "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: command not found"

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, x264, libx264

I am trying to compile the `x264` library for Android, following this [post](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/07/30/cross-compiling-ffmpeg-with-x264-for-android/).

I have cloned the x264 project `git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git` and tried to compile with the following configuration:

```
NDK=~/development/android-ndk-r10c    
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm

./configure \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM \
--host=arm-linux \
--enable-pic \
--enable-static \
--disable-cli
```

The problem is that I get a `No working C compiler found.` error.

The `conftest.log` output:

```
$ cat conftest.log 
./configure: line 153: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: command not found
```

But the `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` is the toolchain's bin folder!!

Looking at this other [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167530/why-cant-i-run-any-android-ndk-commands) it looks like for some reason, even though the file exists, since it is a  64bit Mac, it won't execute the `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc` file and will return this weird error and log.

---

I am in a Mac OS X 10.10 and I have installed the XCode Command Line Tools:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

GCC version:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

---

Can anyone tell me how to fix this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't set `--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-`, you should add that directory to your path first, using `export PATH=$TOOLCHAIN/bin:$PATH`, and only specify `--cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi-` (just as in the post you linked to).

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Ah, because you're setting the toolchain path containing `linux-x86_64` while you're on OS X. Check that the path you're setting in $TOOLCHAIN actually exists - in your case you probably should replace `linux-x86_64` with `darwin-x86_64`.

Comment: This helped me. I had to check the architecture and platform being referenced by the build script actually existed in the location being referenced. Some small tweaks and the build completed successfully.